# How to open a pop-up window based on selected id using radio button and how to pass that selected id to pop-up window, using php,MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I am using mysql_fetch_array() to fetch data from MYSQL and I am displaying that data in the form of HTML table using PHP. HTML Table's first column is primary key of data base table. I added radio button to  it while displaying fetched result. I have UPDATE and DELETE buttons on top of HTML table.  If I select a radio button and click UPDATE/DELETE, a pop-up window should appear to display that selected row values. For this I think I need to pass selected row id/key to 
pop-up window.  If any one know how to achieve it, let me know!

```
<?php
    while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {

 ?>
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td><? echo $rows['ID']; ?></td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="" value=""><? echo $rows['Name']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $rows['Surname']; ?></td>
   <td><? echo $rows['Number']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <?php
 }
?>
```

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: 1. Can you make the title any longer? 2. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated - use either PDO or MySqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform UPDATE and DELETE operation by using below code.

```
<table>
    <tr id="row_1" data-idval="1"><td>1</td>
        <td>XYZZZZ</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
        <td>----</td>
        <td><span class="update">UPDATE</span></td>
        <td><span class="delete">DELETE</span></td>
   </tr>    
   <tr id="row_2" data-idval="2"><td>2</td>
        <td>XYZZZZ</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
        <td>----</td>
        <td><span class="update">UPDATE</span></td>
        <td><span class="delete">DELETE</span></td>
   </tr>  
        <tr id="row_3" data-idval="3"><td>3</td>
        <td>XYZZZZ</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
        <td>----</td>
        <td><span class="update">UPDATE</span></td>
        <td><span class="delete">DELETE</span></td>
   </tr>  
</table>
```

Javascript:-

```
<script type="text/javscript">
function yesnodialog(button1, button2, element){
  var btns = {};
  btns[button1] = function(){ 
      var id_val =  element.parents('tr').data('idval');
      alert(id_val);
      //write here update code using ajax here
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  btns[button2] = function(){ 
      // Do nothing
      $(this).dialog("close");
  };
  $("<div></div>").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    title: 'Condition',
    modal:true,
    buttons:btns
  });
}
$('.update').click(function(){
    yesnodialog('Yes', 'No', $(this));
})


</script>
```

Same you can do for `DELETE` as well.

See live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kXVRe/5/)

Comment: What I need is, first I will select radio button and then I will click UPDATE or DELETE button, after this pop-up window should appear for updating or deleting data from MySQL. So, selected radio button row data should be visible for UPDATE/DELETE in pop-up window after I click UPDATE or DELETE button..I have two seperate buttons for UPDATE and DELETE.

Comment: You want display UPDATE / DELETE for each row or Common UPDATE and DELETE BUTTON?

Comment: I think you need multiple update delete on the basis of selection of user? If yes, then you need checkbox instead of radio button. if you want single UPDATE/ DELETE then remove my update delete td from loop and write outside.

Comment: I don't need multiple update delete, I want just single UPDATE/DELETE. Will try your logic and let you know the outcome.

Comment: If I place table creation logic in while loop using php mysql_fetch_array(), its not working....

Answer (score 0):

please see this code

```
 <td><input type="radio" name="" value="" onclick="alert("<?php echo "you have selected ".$rows['ID']." want to update or delete??"; ?>")"><? echo $rows['Name']; ?></td>
```

hope it will usefulllll